# Why does Clojure's map destructuring look reversed?

Tags: clojure

Destructuring a map looks reversed to me. Can anybody explain what is happening?

I expect that this is the right form of destructuring a map

> ;=> (let [{:a a :b b} {:a 1 :b 2}] [a b])

which returns `Exception Unsupported binding form: :a  clojure.core/destructure/pb--4541 (core.clj:4029)`. Clojure documentations say that below is the right way. But it looks that keys and values are reversed.

This should be the right way:

> ;=> (let [{a :a b :b} {:a 1 :b 2}] [a b])
>   [1 2]

What is happening when destructuring a map?

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/iLOY9e1sYzk/pSgT4w2g_YcJ

Answer (score 6):

It is not really reversed, actually it makes sense. It says: bind to symbol 'a' to value that is associated with the keyword :a

Are you aware of this when your map uses keywords as keys?

```
(let [{:keys [a b]} {:a 1 :b 2}] [a b])
```

Much neater and elegant!

Other variants exist if your keys are symbols or strings.

Comment: Aha, I did not notice that I was using symbols. Actually `(def a 1)` means: assign 1 to symbol named "a"?

Comment: @taro it means: Bind to symbol 'a' the value of 1

Comment: @taro run (doc identical?) in your REPL.

Comment: haha, I am learning Clojure with 'The Joy of Clojure'. Clearing a issue brings another set of questions ;-(

Comment: @taro "The Joy of Clojure" book assumes a knowledge of Clojure. Better to start with something like "Clojure in Action" or "Clojure Programming".

Comment: I am really suprised how rarely "Programming Clojure" by Stuart Halloway is mentioned. I think it's an excellent book for everyone who has a bit of background in programming. @taro What is happening when destructoring a map? `clojure.core/destructure` is invoked with the binding vector. You may study it here: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4001

Comment: Haha, did not consider so much before starting with the book :-O and have gone half-way through... But indeed, going one step back can be faster and more solid approach :-)

Comment: @Chiron during this Christmas time, I went through "Programming Clojure". That answered many of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it makes it possible to distinguish between these to cases:

```
cljs.user=> (let [{foo :foo :as bar} {:foo 3 :as 4}] [foo bar])
[3 {:foo 3, :as 4}]
cljs.user=> (let [{foo :foo bar :as} {:foo 3 :as 4}] [foo bar])
[3 4]
```