# Exact usage of `oracle` function in Korma and the meaning of clojure code?

Tags: clojure, korma, sqlkorma

I'm trying to connect to Oracle database using Korma. First I tried to use this code and successfully connected.

```
(defdb korma-db
  {:classname "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   :subprotocol "oracle"
   :subname "thin:@my.oracle.db:1521:testdb"
   :user "xxx"
   :password "xxx"
   :naming {:keys str/lower-case :fields str/upper-case}})
```

But I found that there is a more convenient function `korma.db.oracle`. So the code looked be simplified like this:

```
(defdb korma-db
  (oracle {:keys ["my.oracle.db" 1521 true]
           :as {:user "xxx" :password "xxx"}
           :naming {:keys str/lower-case :fields str/upper-case}}))
```

But it fails. It tried to `localhost`. When I check the result of `oracle` function, I found out that there's something strange.

```
{:naming {:keys #<string$lower_case clojure.string$lower_case@5ba760ac>,
 :fields #<string$upper_case clojure.string$upper_case@504f4c0b>},
 :as {:user "xxx", :password "xxx"},
 :keys ["my.oracle.db" 1521 true],
 :classname "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
 :subprotocol "oracle:thin",
 :subname "@localhost:1521", :make-pool? true}
            ^^^^^^^^^
```

I checked the Korma source, and the code of `oracle` function is:

```
(defn oracle
  "Create a database specification for an Oracle database. Opts should include keys
  for :user and :password. You can also optionally set host and port."
  [{:keys [host port make-pool?]
    :or {host "localhost", port 1521, make-pool? true}
    :as opts}]
  (merge {:classname "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" ; must be in classpath
          :subprotocol "oracle:thin"
          :subname (str "@" host ":" port)
          :make-pool? make-pool?}
         opts))
```

In short, my questions are:

- What is the exact usage of `oracle` function? What am I missing?
- The code of `oracle` function looks strange for me. Could anyone explain
  the code please, especially the parameter part...`[{:keys [host .... ] :or {...} :as ...}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `oracle` function [destructuring its arguments](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29). Here is an [article about this feature](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html).

So, the right way to call `oracle` is:

```
(defdb korma-db
  (oracle { :user "xxx"
            :password "xxx"
            :host "my.oracle.db"
            :port 1521
            :make-pool? true }))
```

EDIT:
specifying the oracle SID could be done like this:

```
(defdb korma-db
  (oracle {:subname "@//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/testdb"
           :user "xxx"
           :password "xxx"
           :naming {:keys str/lower-case :fields str/upper-case}}))
```

Comment: Thank you. I also found that there was a q&a in stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683770/why-does-clojures-map-destructuring-look-reversed. How could I specify oracle SID?

Comment: No idea, never used korma myself. =)

Comment: I can understand the code now. Unfortunately, I can't test the connectivity right now. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Although I failed to connect to oracle database with the above code, I got to know the important thing, map binding form. And I found a page how to use `oracle` function : https://github.com/korma/Korma/issues/16